# Shared Clipboard between different Mac users

Tags: macos, mac, user-accounts, clipboard, macos-mojave

## How can I share the clipboard among two different users, on macOS Mojave 10.14?

I usually alternate between two users sessions, for separation of concerns, on my MacBook. Sometimes I need to share an information, an URL, or other clipboard piece of data, to the other active user.

The macOS Handoff (Shared Clipboard on devices logged to the same iCloud account) did work once, but then was pretty inconsistent and delayed; often simply not working. ‍♂️

**Is there a way to have a smooth clipboard sharing in a native way, or via some freeware?**

*There are some old answers but they appear outdated and about software that isn't compatible anymore.*

Comment: I think Handoff may be your only option. Allowing the clipboard to pass unchallenged across user sessions would be considered a security risk. The iCloud linkup at least confirms both are "you".

Comment: I'll try to make it work. But isn't there any 3rd party app handling clipboard sharing in a secure-enough way?

Comment: You would need something that makes a physical write to one account's shared folder, then another physical read to retrieve it. I very much doubt anything can un-sandbox itself across 2 accounts otherwise, without iCloud support.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the clipboard to a file you share with the other user:

- Open a terminal window in the source account
- Run: `pbpaste > /tmp/clipboard.txt`
- Change to the target account, and open terminal again
- Run: `pbcopy < /tmp/clipboard.txt`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).